# How do I make AutoHotKey (v2) classes work?

Tags: class, autohotkey

I can't seem to make classes work. I've created this extremely simple code block which doesn't work and displays all the issues I'm having.

Any help in getting classes to work would be very much appreciated.

Running the below code results in `Error: This value of type "Class" has no method named "new".`

```
#Requires AutoHotkey v2.0

class Application {
    new(AppName) {
        this.name := AppName
    }
   
    Msg() {
        MsgBox("My application name is: " this.name)
    }
} 

runtest() {
    App := Application.new("ExpressVPN")
    App.Msg()
}

runtest()
```

I've tried using different method names such as `__new` instead of `new`.

Declaring `App := Application.new("ExpressVPN")` as `App := new Application("ExpressVPN")` results in 'Warning: This variable appears to never be assigned a value.'

I've been at this for two days and the provided code block is extremely simplified to make it easier to identify issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not a big fan or user of AHK v2, but this can give you some point to start.

```
#Requires AutoHotkey v2.0

class Application {


    static new(AppName) {

        this.name := AppName

    }
   
    static Msg() {

        MsgBox("My application name is: " this.name)

    }


} 

runtest(AppName) {

    Application.new(AppName)
    Application.Msg()

}

runtest("ExpressVPN")
runtest("AnotherApp")
```

Comment: Fantastic! It seems to do something. Running into the issue where it will display `ExpressVPN` for both messageboxes now, so it seems it doesn't 'drop' the first object. Do you know why?

I'm trying to build an array of objects to pass to a function that needs to be able to look at all the various application attributes simultaneously.

Thanks a lot already!

Comment: Nevermind my last! Error on my part (didn't pas AppName to Application.new()).